# How to use case_when with rowwise for evaluating missing values

Tags: r, dplyr, rowwise

I have data with many missing values and I want to calculate the maximum of each row of all non-missing values.
I use a case_when, because I don't want to calculate maximum for rows that are all NA.

Example:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(col_a = rep(c(2, 1, NA_real_), each = 2), 
               col_b = rep(c(2, 1, NA_real_), times = 2)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(count_not_na = sum(!is.na(c(col_a, col_b))),
         max_value = case_when(count_not_na > 0 ~ max(c(col_a, col_b), na.rm = T),
                                                      T ~ NA_real_))
```

I get the intended output, i.e.:

| col_a | cvol_b | count_not_na | max_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | NA | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| NA | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| NA | NA | 0 | NA |

Although the code works as intended, I get the following warning:

```
Warning message:
There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
ℹ In argument: `max_value = case_when(...)`.
ℹ In row 6.
Caused by warning in `max()`:
! no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Apparantly, the case-when doesn't work as I wanted beacuse in row 6, the maximum value shouldn't be evaluated as all values are NA.

What I am missing here? How to write the above more "beautiful"?

I happy for any suggestions! Thank you!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Hi Mael, I added the output. The output is not wrong with the code I used, however it didn't work as expected because the case_when wasn't used as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pmax`:

```
data <- tibble(col_a = rep(c(2, 1, NA_real_), each = 2), 
               col_b = rep(c(2, 1, NA_real_), times = 2))

data %>% 
  mutate(
    count_not_na = rowSums(!is.na(.[1:2])), 
    max_value = pmax(col_a, col_b, na.rm = TRUE))
```

**Output**:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  col_a col_b count_not_na max_value
  <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>     <dbl>
1     2     2            2         2
2     2     1            2         2
3     1    NA            1         1
4     1     2            2         2
5    NA     1            1         1
6    NA    NA            0        NA
```

Comment: Not sure if rowwise is needed here.

Comment: Why are you doing it in `rowwise()`? `pmax` is doing a parallel operation. You can simply do `pmax(data$col_a, data$col_b, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: yes completely right, will remove it. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! It works fine. Do I understand correctly, that there is only pmax and pmin in base R, i.e. to compute mean or median or count the na, I have to get back to my initial try?

Comment: I made an edit.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on `case_when` is explicit that all branches are evaluated before the appropriate case picked; Therefore warnings fired in failed branches that you didnt intend to be explored are at issue and there are two approaches

1. switch to a conditional mechanism that doesnt work by evaluating everything, for example the `base::ifelse` function
2. wrap your functions that can fail/error/warn so that the failure messages are smothered when using case_when. for example `{purrr}` package gives convenient wrapper functions; quietly,safely,possibly etc.